# Form HTML not getting updated.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here's something weird

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="test" value="abc" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
$('form').submit(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   alert($(this).html()); 
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F6XvW/

I change the value of the input field, then click submit to get the HTML, but the value is not updated inside the HTML? What's up with that? How to get the updated HTML?

Comment: The attribute "Value" does not change when changing property values of an input element.

Comment: Are you trying to get the HTML of the form or are you trying to get the updated value of your input "test"?

Comment: You're have to Use $('test'). val() to get the valute of your input.  If you want to get all  form values in serialized format for  ajax, use $(this).serialize()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the user inputs is never changing the HTML. It's a form value which will be sent as a parameter to the server.

See here: [your jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/F6XvW/2/):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="test" placeholder="abc" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
$('form').submit(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   alert('inputted value = ' + $(this).find('input[type=text]').val()); 
});
</script>
```

---

If you really want to update the DOM, you have to manually set it: http://jsfiddle.net/F6XvW/3/

**JS**

```
$('form').submit(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   $('#test').attr("value", $('#test').val());
   alert('changed input value to: ' + $(this).find('input[type=text]').val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the input of a value does not change the Document Object Model (DOM).

**SOLUTION**

```
$('form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var newinputval = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val();
    var newhtml = $(this).html();
    newhtml = newhtml.replace("abc", newinputval);
    alert(newhtml);
});
```

As you see I first receive the new input value, then I get the HTML and replace the DOM's value with the current input value. Now it does exactly the thing that you want.

[`JSFiddle demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/CNL8C/)

Answer (score 2):

The `value` **attribute** shows the *default value*, not the *current value* (which is available in the DOM property of the same name.

If you want to get the current value, then you would have to loop over all the form controls and get their values from the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading out the initial HTML - changing value on the page will not change in this HTML. Try:

```
$('form').submit(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   alert($('#test').val()); 
});
```

...to get the value of the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get value of any input use

```
$('form').submit(function(ev){
       ev.preventDefault();
       alert($("#test").val()); 
    });

$('input').val();
```

in forms you can use **.serialize();**